# Excel VB module Text to Hex

Tags: vba, unicode, hex

I need to convert text to hex code points in excel if possible. The text is something like this:

```
Тест текст
```

and i need to get code points without spaces like this:

```
0422043504410442002004420435043A044104420020
```

Can someone help me? Thank you.
I can do it in php, or java, but can not wrap my head around this in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on line:

```
Function Uni2Hex(Txt As String) As String
Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To Len(Txt)
        Uni2Hex = Uni2Hex & Right("000" & hex(AscW(Mid(Txt, n, 1))), 4)
    Next n
End Function
```

Comment: This really should have been edited into your question. It is not an answer.